# Executing SVN cleanup from command prompt

Tags: svn

I want to execute SVN cleanup from the command prompt. However, I cannot do it on the root folder since it takes long time to cleanup, and secondly, the machine runs out of memory.

I have 60+ folders on which cleanup has to be executed. I have written a script that picks one folder at a time and cleans it.

The problem is that after each cleanup, there is a pop-up message stating that cleanup has succeeded. But this pop-up message blocks the execution of the script until I press OK on it.

Is there a option to not have this pop-up message if the cleanup succeeds?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try option --non-interactive (: do no interactive prompting):

```
svn cleanup --non-interactive
```

Comment: I am on Windows and using TortoiseProc.exe. I tried with the non-interactive option as you suggested, but didnt work:

Here is what I executed:
TortoiseProc.exe /command:cleanup --non-interactive /path:<complete_path>

Further help please.

Comment: I'd suggest using native svn command line tools, for example SlikSvn: http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download. The reason is that command line for this tool is standard, not dependent on OS.

Comment: And I think you should not expect non-interactive mode from the GUI tool, which Tortoise SVN is.

Comment: Tortoise uses /noui /noprogressui and /nodlg to control visibility of dialogs.  See the help file, all the command lines are fully documented.

Comment: current version of tortoise has command line support with traditional svn command. If you don't have it, fetch fresh version, and under install, select option for installing command line tools. In some past versions, cmd tools were unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

You can create such a .bat file also;

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:cleanup /path:"YourDirectory" /cleanup /externals /noui /closeonend:2
```