# How can I delete all unversioned files folders in windows

Tags: svn

I have a working copy of a Subversion repository, is there a way to delete all unversioned or ignored files in that working copy with a single command or tool?
Need a optimal solution that should delete all the unversioned folders and files in both list view as well as tree view

I have used following code

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("svn.exe", "status --non-interactive");
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = directory;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    if (line.Length > 7)
                    {
                        if (line[0] == '?')
                        {
                            string relativePath = line.Substring(8);
                            Console.WriteLine(relativePath);

                            string path = Path.Combine(directory, relativePath);

                            if (Directory.Exists(path))
                            { 
                                DeleteDir(path);
                            }
                            else if (File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
                                file.IsReadOnly = false;
                                File.Delete(path);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                }

            }
        }

        static void DeleteDir(string root)
        {

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(root);
            FileInfo[] fis = di.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
            {
                fi.IsReadOnly = false;
                File.Delete(fi.FullName);
            }


            foreach (DirectoryInfo dinfo in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                DeleteDir(dinfo.FullName);
            }
            if (di.GetDirectories().Length == 0) { Directory.Delete(di.FullName); return; }

        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090507/executing-svn-cleanup-from-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this process using TortoiseSVN :

- right-click on working copy folder while holding the shift-key down
- choose "delete unversioned items"

Comment: Hi andro, thank you but need to use that in command line.is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

```
svn status | grep ^\? | sed -e 's/^.......\(.*\)$/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' | xargs -Ifile rm -rf file
```

Reference : https://artofsoftware.org/2012/03/30/svn-command-line-to-remove-unversioned-files/